# request with two limit statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this request

`select * from tab where id < 100 order by time desc, type desc limit 1000 OFFSET 0 LIMIT 20`

I want to get the 1000 first rows 20 by 20.

I have always a syntax error.

Comment: _1000 first rows 20 by 20?_

Comment: In fact the '20' is the number of row per page. so it will be changed every request. To summarize I want to get the 1000 first row split on several requests (every response contain 20 rows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you *could* use a subquery:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*
      from tab t
      where id < 100
      order by time desc, type desc
      limit 1000
     ) t
order by time desc, type desc
OFFSET 0 LIMIT 20;
```

But I would just control the number of rows fetched at the application layer.